# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms

## my views.py file

```
class Home(TemplateView):

    @staticmethod
    def get_name(request):
        form = NameForm() #function in forms.py
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {'form': form})

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        global text
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
            # i dont where is the error anyone plz help
        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', args)
```

Comment: Your `post` does not return a response, furthermore a `get(..)` and `post(..)` can have more parameters.

Comment: You probably also did *not* use the `.as_view(..)` in the `urls.py`?

Comment: Why do you use a `global` here by the way?

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use a [**`FormView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView). This view also has a [**`TemplateResponseMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#templateresponsemixin), so in essence it is a [**`TemplateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView), but with a form. The nice thing is that Django implements most of the "boilerplate code", so the amount you need to do is very limited.

You can then render it like:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class Home(FormView):
    form_class = NameForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(text=form.cleaned_data['your_name'])
        )
```

and that's it. The `FormView` automatically adds a template variable `form` to the context data, and in case the form is valid the `form_valid` function is called, and we then pass `text` to the context.

Typically if the form is valid, it is not very common however to render a response. If the POST has side-effects, one better implements the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Here however there are no side-effects, so it is ok.